# Правильно ли установлен Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Сервер смотрит в папку `domain.com/web` в этой папке лежит сам фреймворк, т.е. yii.bat, .bowerrc, .gitignore и т.п. служебные файлы. А так же папки:

`frontend/web`

и

`backend/web`

В которых уже index.php Это же неправильно вроде. Фреймворк должен лежать выше www (web) директории? Но так корректно работает htaccess разруливающий запросы к фронтенд и бекенд приложению:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin(\/?.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule ^(\/?.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
```

Если же перенастроить что бы сервер смотрел не в `web` а куда-то в другую папку глубже, то htaccess напрочь перестаёт корректно разделять запросы на forntend и backend. То же самое если фреймворк переложить на уровень выше в `domain.com` Как поступать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день.
В advanced показан один из вариантов(от разработчиков), как разделить приложение на "frondend" и "backend".
Вы же можете сделать свою структуру. И настройкой одного ".htaccess" здесь не ограничишься, надо ещё править файлы "index.php" в "backend/web" и "frontend/web".
Если это сделать на примере "basic" шаблона, то действия должны быть следующими:
1) Переносим все служебные директории в отдельную, назовём её, например, "yii".
2) Настраиваем сервер так, чтобы он "смотрел" в директорию "web"
3) Редактируем файл index.php в директории "web", заменяем пути к нужным файлам. Например:

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../yii/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
  require(__DIR__ . '/../yii/config/web.php'),
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

И тогда структура будет более "правильной")))